# error when getting TransactionReceipt from parity node with ethereum-go

Tags: parity, golang

In my golang oracle, I need to get the `TransactionReceipt` for my transaction.

To do so I call `client.TransactionReceipt(context.TODO(), txHash)`

This yields a transaction receipt when the node is geth but fails when the node is parity. The error message is `json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go struct field Receipt.root of type hexutil.Bytes`

I'm guessing this has something to do with the JSON returned by the nodes but I can't see any errors.

The JSON returned by GETH is:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x88ed2d126dc004b56309da73a897dee7601a03fa6aa4133f8b942646fe71b995",
  blockNumber: 1,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  transactionHash: "0x182eb16fa75d58e16b2ac13ba3697ad00a2a961f2d7cbb6c15e3c17fd262c267",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

and the one returned by Parity is:

```
{
  blockHash: "0x28f5afbde2ffe91f409f91b27ebe75d963326bfa79e72f29492692d06f48427a",
  blockNumber: 643,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
  gasUsed: 21000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  root: null,
  status: null,
  transactionHash: "0xe7cf7d79c52fdec083706b51dca3aa3374b00a3d8276708e632387f8b1cdbfc1",
  transactionIndex: 0
}
```

The only difference I can see are the 2 additional fields `root` and `status` but these exist in the type declaration of the receipt:

```
type Receipt struct {
    // Consensus fields
    PostState         []byte   `json:"root"`
    Status            uint     `json:"status"`
    CumulativeGasUsed *big.Int `json:"cumulativeGasUsed" gencodec:"required"`
    Bloom             Bloom    `json:"logsBloom"         gencodec:"required"`
    Logs              []*Log   `json:"logs"              gencodec:"required"`

    // Implementation fields (don't reorder!)
    TxHash          common.Hash    `json:"transactionHash" gencodec:"required"`
    ContractAddress common.Address `json:"contractAddress"`
    GasUsed         *big.Int       `json:"gasUsed" gencodec:"required"`
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from the `json` unmarshaller.

The `Receipt` provides the `UnmarshalJSON` method which is used by the `json` std lib to decode the bytes. If we look at the [method definition](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/types/gen_receipt_json.go#L37) we can see that:

- it is using a different local `Receipt` type to do automatic decoding.
- the local type has field `PostState hexutil.Bytes` which maps to the `"root"` JSON key (look at the `json:"root"` tag).

In the parity log `root` has value `null` and `json` unmarshaller tries to decode it into `hexutil.Bytes` and then convert it into `[]byte`.  `hexutil.Bytes` is just a redefinition of `[]byte` which provides [custom decoding](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/common/hexutil/json.go#L48), which fails if the source doesn't satisfy `isString` predicate:

```
func isString(input []byte) bool {
    return len(input) >= 2 && input[0] == '"' && input[len(input)-1] == '"'
}
```

Since this is a custom decoder, it passes input as raw bytes. In case of parity log it's (`[]byte("null")`) - it doesn't start (and end) with quotemark (`"`), so it fails.

The `hexutil` library has a specific [test-case](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/common/hexutil/json_test.go#L65) for that so it doesn't seem to be a bug, but a desired feature.